# how to synchronize two threads with even number and odd number function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-multithreading

how to synchronize two threads with even number and odd number function in python

it has to return values like below:

```
fun1 odd = 1
fun2 even =2
fun1 odd = 3
fun2 even =4
fun1 odd = 5
fun2 even =6
```

Please any one help on this.

Comment: More background would be welcome -- are these threads workers? Should they start executing tasks in order, or only report results in order? Are all the tasks available in advance? Or is it a round-robin scheduler, in which case, should these threads be scheduled only if they both reach critical section, or should each thread wait for another regardless (and possibly deadlock)?

Comment: What you are looking is, perhaps, called "token passing" or "passing the baton" in different domains.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "[Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects)" for this purpose like this example:

```
import threading


class PrintNumbers(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, start_number, end_number, step, set_event, clear_event):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start_number = start_number
        self.end_number = end_number
        self.step = step
        self.set_event = set_event
        self.clear_event = clear_event

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.start_number, self.end_number, self.step):
            print(i)
            self.set_event.set()
            self.clear_event.clear()
            self.clear_event.wait()
        self.set_event.set()


threading_event1 = threading.Event()
threading_event2 = threading.Event()

t1 = PrintNumbers(0, 10, 2, threading_event1, threading_event2)
t2 = PrintNumbers(1, 10, 2, threading_event2, threading_event1)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

This code creates two events, one event for setting it in a thread and another for clearing in same thread. Each thread sets another's event and waits for it's event after clearing it.

Comment: Is it the one threading synchronization ?Amin please let me know about synchronization

Comment: You can extend this code like this (suppose threads like a loop and use the next's event as set event):

`threading_event1 = threading.Event()`
`threading_event2 = threading.Event()`
`threading_event3 = threading.Event()`

`t1 = PrintNumbers(0, 10, 3, threading_event1, threading_event2)`
`t2 = PrintNumbers(1, 10, 23 threading_event2, threading_event3)`
`t3 = PrintNumbers(2, 10, 3, threading_event3, threading_event1)`
`